# Structuring complex data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to allow users to upload a CSV mailing list and to insert it into elasticsearch.

Any user can define any fields they want wihtin their CSV and I would import it into elasticsearch with the exceptions of the `email` field which should be in all of them and a `userid` field which is internal and is used to filter queries for a specific user when he wants to view the mailing lists he uploaded in the past.

Initially I thought I would just create an index for each mailing list, since fields in each CSV are dynamic and can include just the `email` or other fields such as `firstname` `lastname` etc.. But then I read that elasticsearch doesn't really cope well with a lot of indexes.

How would you structure the index(es) to such an app? Should I create one index where I would just push data in and whatever fields that are added and create aliases for each `userid`?

Comment: How many mailing lists (indices) do you believe you'll have? And what is your cluster setup?

Comment: Also, have you checked [this link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/user-based.html) and [this one](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shared-index.html)?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm expecting to have hundreds of thousands of mailing lists, I would like to get feedback on how I should set up my cluster as well, currently I'm just playing around with a single node but obviously I would run a cluster at some point.

Comment: :-) then definitely no multiple indices.

Comment: @AndreiStefan How would you go about designing the cluster and indexes of such an application? Those links are nice but they mainly speak about sharding certain user groups but that doesn't really answer my question. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Consider using `object` type fields in your index: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html#_dynamic and using the `dynamic` property it should add fields automatically to your mapping. And I suggest starting experimenting with this, as well as your new cluster. No cluster can be defined like: you should have X nodes with Y heap size and Z type CPU. Start with a setup and test. Also, I recommend [this presentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/webinars/elasticsearch-pre-flight-checklist/) that should help in your decisions.

Comment: A few questions.. I guess apart from email id and user id, all the other fields are dynamic. Which means any mailing list might or might not contain the field and any mailing list can add new field as well. Then I would suggest you to keep a single index single type with no predefined mapping. Mapping would be formed during time of bulk insert. Pros1.) best for quering. 2.) no associations. Totally flat data which I guess elasticsearch is all about. 3.) ever scalable since you can always add new fields.